# Showing an integer in an android app with xml

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my java-code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int intValue = 100;

    TextView intText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.intTextId);
    intText.setText(""+intValue);

}
```

And here is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/intTextId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried reading on this site and mimicking the different solutions that exists, but for some reason, it doesn't show anything. Any help would be much appriciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried String.valueOf(intValue)?

Comment: Yes, and that gives the same empty box...

Comment: Remove the padding attributes and try again.  What happens?

Comment: Still nothing I'm afraid... Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Does the logcat show any errors in this case or does it seem to work prerfectly fine? If it's throwing an error, can you post that?

Comment: It doesn't show any error or any warning whatsoever...

Comment: Okey, so apparently my intValue shows in the AVD (Android Virtual Device), but it doesn't show up on the graphical layout. Is it supposed to do that? If it is, my code seems to be working! :)

Comment: @Zantonius The graphical layout in Eclipse doesn't run your `onCreate()` method, so yes, it is supposed to do that.

Comment: Ah, okey! Thanks @Code-Guru and everyone else!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the this. Where ur casting the text view and just do like :

intText.setText(""+String.value of(intValue));

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't that your TextView isn't displaying the integer value

```
intText.setText(""+intValue);
```

should work absolutely fine.  I'd suggest doing some testing to determine where your TextView is appearing in the LinearLayout, chances are your TextView isn't actually on screen.